# Encryption and Decryption in Blazor WASM and Aspnet core API

Tags: javascript, encryption, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor WASM, I have this js code

```
function encrypt(plainText, key) {
    debugger;
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, keyBytes, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    const encryptedText = iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    return encryptedText;
}
```

In my API, I try to decrypt this using this algorithm

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var iv = new byte[16];
            var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Both the js code and C# code use the same key which is `private const string INITIAL_KEY = @"mPqqfIRf74nIJiO4";`

I can decrypt the text coming from the client but the problem is it is prepended by unreadable characters. This is the sample output

PLAIN TEXT IN THE CLIENT `encryptedMessage`

DECRYPTION IN THE SERVER `���������|����^encryptedMessage`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In the CryptoJS code IV and ciphertext are concatenated, in the C# code the separation of both is missing. Instead of the actual IV a wrong IV is used (namely an IV consisting of 16 0x00 values).

In CBC mode, an incorrect IV will result only in an incorrect first block. Therefore, in your result the first block is displayed as gibberish, while the rest is decrypted correctly.

The problem can be solved by separating IV and ciphertext. This can be done using the known length of the IV (16 bytes):

```cs
//var iv = new byte[16];
//var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
var ivCiphertext = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
var iv = ivCiphertext[..16];
var buffer = ivCiphertext[16..];
```

With this change, decryption with the C# code works.